# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbconnection, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have installed the 'Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable' as described in the blog entry

http://danielcai.blogspot.com/2011/02/solution-run-jet-database-engine-on-64.html

and it works in my windows-forms application. I now want to add some unit-tests and when running the unit-test I get the above error. I have checked my references but can't seem to figure out why it works in the application and not in the unit-test.

I'm working in VS2010 on a windows 7 ultimate x64 installation.

Can someone please help me ?

Comment: Is it possible that your unit test project is compiled to a different bitness (32 or 64) than your application project?

Comment: Yup, there is not redistributable for a 64-bit version available.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: The downloadwebsite from microsoft ist a copy&paste error from Access 2007 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

The Provider for 2007 (only in 32bit available) : "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0”
The Provider for 2010 (32/64bit) : "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0”

Comment: booh, i was wrong - the provider is always "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0” regardless if you are using office 2007/2010/2013

Answer (score 2):

The Target Platform is probably set to Any CPU, which means when you run it from VS or in your 64-bit Windows it will execute as 64-bit code (and use the 64-bit Jet driver). But a typical unit test runner is executing in 32-bit mode and all assemblies it loads will then execute in 32-bit mode (since your project target platform is Any, ie either 32 or 64 bit). And Windows 7 does not come with a 32-bit Jet driver by default.

Comment: The default target for VS2010 is x86 actually.  But yes, surely the cause of the problem.

Comment: You are correct, it used to be default Any in VS2008. But it can still be set to Any (maybe imported from earlier VS)